# Multi tenant django application using URL mappings instead of domain mappings

Tags: python, django, url-routing, multi-tenant, pythonanywhere

In django, most multi-tenant implementations (modules) are mapping hosts onto views.

e.g. mapping host/URL -> django view using postgress schema's:

```
customer1.myapp.com/view1/arg1 -> myapp.view1(arg1)  using schema 'customer1'
customer2.myapp.com/view1/arg1 -> myapp.view1(arg1)  using schema 'customer2'
customer3.myapp.com/view1/arg1 -> myapp.view1(arg1)  using schema 'customer3'
```

Since my PaaS (Pythonanywhere) is not  supporting wildcard domains (*.myapp.com), I am trying to set up a multi-tenant application using URL mapping:

e.g. mapping URL -> django view:

```
myapp.com/customer1/view1/arg1 ->  myapp.view1(arg1) passing implicit parameter tenant='customer1'
myapp.com/customer2/view1/arg1 ->  myapp.view1(arg1) passing implicit parameter tenant='customer2'
myapp.com/customer3/view1/arg1 ->  myapp.view1(arg1) passing implicit parameter tenant='customer3'
```

Here some middleware should take care of passing the tenant parameter to the view and filtering query results for objects applicable to the selected tenant.
e.g. https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

But question here is: How to do this -which package can handle this- for URL mapping instead of host mapping?

Note: django-multitenants mentions "Supports url patterns as well as sub-domains" but not clear how to do this...
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multitenants

Answer (score 1):

Solved with great help from Pythonanywhere support in following way:

1. Create a new webapp for each tenant (yes, this is costing 2$ / month)
2. Map the new domain to the new webapp (check pythonanywhere web tab "DNS setup")
3. Have each webapp use the same code and the same postgres database (copy static & media patsh & wsgi script)
4. Create the new schema in the postgres DB
5. The rest is easy: follow the documentation of [django-tenant-schemas](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Roughly:

- Sync the new schema: ./manage.py migrate_schemas --schema=my-new-tenant
- Add the new tenant to the public tenant "customers_client" table
- And if your user model is NOT in the public table: create new admin user for this tenant:  ./manage.py createsuperuser --schema=my-new-tenant

Answer (score 0):

From a bit of poking around in `django-multitenants`, it looks like it's meant to support URL-based multitenancy using a setting called `TENANT_BASE_PATH`

However... if you [search the codebase of the project on GitHub](https://github.com/ojengwa/django-multitenants/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=TENANT_BASE_PATH), the only references to that setting appear in the documentation, not in the code itself.  So it may be that `django-multitenants` isn't a finished project, but rather a work-in-progress that may have been abandoned (last commit was just 14 days after the initial commit).